# How can I use buildroot for my development machine in addition to my target?

Tags: multiplatform, buildroot

I am developing a for an embedded target using buildroot, adding our custom applications as new packages.

These packages depend on some non standard libraries(which we already integrated into buildroot) that are painful to install natively on the development workstations. Can I use buildroot out-of-tree builds to compile the applications for my development machines to test them as well? Assuming all the libraries are in place, they are generic linux applications that should not have problem running on PCs.

Is there a more convenient way to manage both builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only supported way is to use a "crosscompiler" for your host system.

See [buildroot environment with host toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833672/buildroot-environment-with-host-toolchain)